# unable to capture Enter within a textbox

Tags: dojo

I am struggling with capturing the Enter event within a textbox and have tried several different examples with no luck so far.  The textbox is within a table within a widget template html.  I am on dojo 1.9.

Here is the definition inside the template file:

```
<td id="BBC"><input type="text" name="SrchWithin"
placeholder="Search within Last Name" id="SrchWithin"
dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" value="" style="width: 12em;" />
/td>
```

Here are some attempts based a number of examples on the web:

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox"]);
require(["dojo/on","dojo/keys"],
function(on, keys) {
  on(digit.byId("SrchWithin"), "keypress", function(evt) {
  console.log("key = " + evt.charOrCode);
  });
});
```

That attempt ended up with digit not defined.

Most others just never got an event:

```
var taskDblClkHndl = dojo.connect(dojo.byId("SrchWithin"), "onKeyUp", function(event) {
  console.log("key pressed");
});


require([ "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/keys",
"dojo/domReady!" ], function(domConstruct, on, query, keys) {
  query("input[type='text']").on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log("event.keyCode" + event.keyCode);
  });
});

<script
type="dojo/connect" event="onKeyDown" args="evt">
  var key = evt.charOrCode;
  if (key == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
    console.log("dojo.keys.ENTER");
  }
</script>
```

So many ways to do this, and I cannot get one working...  Any comments on what I am missing?

**Update:**  perhaps it is a matter of context of where I am attempting this code...
I put the following code where I was trying the suggestion using the query and it does NOT show the input fields I expected:

```
var testit = dojo.query("input, button, textarea, select",  this.domNode).forEach(
function(inputElem) {
    console.log(inputElem);
    }
);
```

However, when I added this same code to the postCreate() method in my widget.js file, I did find the SrchWithin textbox...  Not sure yet how to add this code to the widget or if I can use an attach point from my main.jsp file...

Comment: Your examples/attempts seem to be kind of all over the place - are you trying to capture keyboard events for dijit widgets or just input elements directly?  Are you using legacy Dojo or AMD?  `digit.byId` would never be defined since Dojo's widget library is `dijit`, not `digit`.

Comment: The attempts are all over the place because I am trying as many solutions as I can searching this topic :-)  I have a textbox defined within a template.  The definition is above.  I want to know when Enter is pressed in that textbox.  I did correct the "digit" issue and now I get TypeError: dijit.byId is not a function.  I am using AMD.

Guilherme, I tried that code, and never got a console.log msg.

I am putting this code in the main .jsp file after I have created the widget.  I am using the id from the html (id="SrchWithin")

Comment: Added an update to my problem description with code sample.  Based on some code I have for dumping input fields, the context appears wrong, it is not dumping the fields from the widget.  Investigating further.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Take a look at this code snippet:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvq2u0wj/)

Just this part of the code should have been enough for you to get what you wanted working:

```
require([ "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/keys", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(domConstruct, on, query, keys) {
    query("input[type='text']").on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log("event.keyCode" + event.keyCode);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me...  I added an data-dojo-attach-event

```
<td id="BBC"><input type="text" name="SrchWithin"
placeholder="Search within Last Name" id="SrchWithin"
dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" value="" style="width: 12em;" 
data-dojo-attach-point="SrchWithinAttach"
data-dojo-attach-event="onKeyUp:keyPressed" />
</td>
```

Then added the method keyPressed() to my custom widget (this example uses keys, so have to a dojo/keys to require and function list...)

```
keyPressed : function(event){
if (event.keyCode === keys.ENTER) {
  console.log("Enter pressed...");
  }
},
```

I am still struggling to get the value of the textbox...
Have tried registry.byId("SrchWithin"), but var assigned is undefined
Also dijit.byId but it returned dijit.byId is not a function.

So, I tried adding parser.parse(), but that failed saying the BorderContainer that includes the textbox "is already registered"

**UPDATE:** this worked for me:

```
var box0 = dojo.byId("SrchWithin");
console.log(box0.value)
```

Thanks again for the suggestions.